# 2 rows of 2 squares, separated and centered (CSS/HTML)

Tags: html, css

I didnt find an answer to this, so:

I am trying to do this in my blog:
- 2 rows (using div tag, not table)
- In each row, there will be a square image of certain size in percentage of width (e.g. 40%, I dont know how to set height to keep square form) and a color square with text inside, from the same size as the image.

```html
square image                text inside square

text inside square          square image
```

I have this so far:

```html
    <style type="text/css">
    .element {
     float:left;
            width: 50vh;
            height:50vh;
     border: 1px solid #000000;
     margin:0 10px 0 0;
     margin-left:5%;
     margin-right:5%;
     margin-top:10%;
     align:center;
    }
    </style>
    
<div class="element">
  <img src="wp-content/uploads/2015/04/luices.jpg" alt="Mountain View" width="400px">
</div>
<div class="element">Some text</div>
    
<div class="element">Some text</div>
<div class="element">
 <img src="wp-content/uploads/2015/04/luices.jpg" alt="Mountain View" width="400px">
</div>
```

But have many problems:

1- I dont know how to use "vh" in width, and also, as far as I know, Browser compatibility is a problem with it. I just want to place these two squares 40% of width each one, separated by 7% of width (from sides and from each other).The same for the second row.

2- I need mobile compatibility also.

3- When you open the website in a small window (or phone), the second square will go down (thats ok) but I need that the order of squares to be:

```html
square image 
text inside square
square image 
text inside square
```

Which is different from what every browser does with my code, wich is keeping the same original order: image,text,text,image.

I hope I explained well.

Thank you very much.
Bob

Answer (score -1):

So in order to get the correct layout on a mobile device, you need to use the

```
@media
```

attribute, to set the css properties to be mobile friendly.

I made a plnkr that I tested on both my desktop and nexus 5, the key though are these two css properties:

```
  div.row{
    min-height: 25vh;
    margin-bottom: 4vw;
  }

  div.col-40{
    background-color: #333;
    width: 44vw;
    min-height: 25vh; /* set to the same as div.row min-height  */
    max-height: 25vh; /* set to the same as div.row min-height  */
    margin-left: 1vw;
    padding: 1vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/d2C3xOiNYjaUqVeX2yf4?p=preview

Basically you need to wrap the div's that you want next to each other, in another div, in this case .row.

If you have images that are larger than the div, the overflow will be hidden. You will more than likely need to mess with the css for your blog, but hopefully this gets you where you need to be.

You also should probably be using vw for the width properties (vw = viewport width). 1 vw or 1 vh = 1/100th of the viewport width or height.

The float:left; more than likely is messing up the div order. I prefer to use a display:inline-block; with a relational width value, as done with vw.